# Is there an array function in PHP to do this instead of a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP, is there an array function do the same thing as the code below? I'm wondering if it's possible with something like `array_map` or `array_reduce` in such a way that the `$items` array does not need to be declared beforehand.

```
$data = [
  ['order_product_id' => 123, 'quantity' => 1],
  ['order_product_id' => 456, 'quantity' => 2],
  ['order_product_id' => 567, 'quantity' => 3],
];

$items = [];

foreach ($data as $item) {
  $items[$item->order_product_id] = ['quantity' => $item->quantity];
}

print_r($items);

/*
Array
(
    [123] => ['quantity' => 1]
    [456] => ['quantity' => 2]
    [789] => ['quantity' => 3]
)
*/
```

Comment: is there a problem with using foreach()?

Comment: There is no problem. It's just a question.

Comment: Why the vehement prohibition of initializng `$items`? Do you want to modify `$data` in place?

Comment: I am really becoming baffled by all the downvotes on SO. I asked a pretty straight-forward, 100% programming-based question with the intent of learning some of the more advanced aspects of PHP. Somehow this question gets downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) will do what you want as it hides the declaration of the output array in the 'initial value' of the 'carry' or 'accumulator' parameter. Also, rather than 'reduce' it actually adds entries to the output.

imo, It is more useful to think of the `carry` parameter to the `callback` as an `accumulator`. In this case, the 'accumulator' is an array, that we are adding entries to.

imo, It isn't as easy to understand as the original version. And is no faster.

```
$data = [
  (object) ['order_product_id' => 123, 'quantity' => 1],
  (object) ['order_product_id' => 456, 'quantity' => 2],
  (object) ['order_product_id' => 567, 'quantity' => 3],
];


$items = array_reduce($data, 
            function ($out, $item) {
                $out[$item->order_product_id] = ['quantity' => $item->quantity];
                return $out;                                    
            },
            array());

print_r($items);
```

Output:

```
Array(
    [123] => Array([quantity] => 1)

    [456] => Array([quantity] => 2)

    [567] => Array([quantity] => 3)
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to do that:

```
<?php
$data = [
  ['order_product_id' => 123, 'quantity' => 1],
  ['order_product_id' => 456, 'quantity' => 2],
  ['order_product_id' => 567, 'quantity' => 3],
];

$items = [];

array_map(function ($item) use (&$items) {
    $items[$item['order_product_id']] = ['quantity' => $item['quantity']];
}, $data);
```

You can use two array_map calls to do this too:

```
$keys = array_map(function ($item) {
    return $item['order_product_id'];
}, $data);

$values = array_map(function ($item) {
    return  ['quantity' => $item['quantity']];
}, $data);

$items = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Or if you don't want to declare any temporary variables:

```
$items = array_combine(
    array_map(function ($item) {
        return $item['order_product_id'];
    }, $data), 
    array_map(function ($item) {
        return  ['quantity' => $item['quantity']];
    }, $data)
);
```

None of them are as efficient as `foreach`.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. Is there any way to do it without having to declare the `$items` array first?

Comment: AKAIK there is no default php function to replace an array key the way you want. There a lot of ways of getting $items, though. I can name you a few, if you want.

Comment: I agree with Waldson here. There is no default function. The interpretation of `array_map` is essentially the same as a foreach. You're overcomplicating your issue flyingL123.

Comment: [Ryan Vincent's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40252418/736864) is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your thorough response though. I am just trying to learn some of the more advanced aspects of the language. This spot in my code seemed like a good opportunity to do that.